# Select column values as column names

Tags: sql-server-2005, pivot, union

I have the following table: tb_answers

The table structure is as follows

```
ID | QUESTIONID | SURVEYID | LEAGUEID | MEMBERID | ANSWER | DATEADDED | DIVISIONID
```

Sample data

```
302347 | 2336 | 172 | 146 | 68 | 467 Vallie Lane | 2012-05-21 16:36:22.433 | 0
302350 | 2340 | 172 | 146 | 68 | 591             | 2012-05-21 16:36:22.483 591
```

I need to present this data as follows.

```
DYNNAMIC LIST OF QUESTION#QUESTIONID# | MEMBERID | DIVISION
DYNNAMIC LIST OF VALUES OF QUESTION#QUESTIONID#|#MEMBERID#|DIVISION
```

So I can sort by the value of `QUESTION#QUESTIONID#`

This possible? I'm not good with pivot and union, so any help is appreciated.

Comment: It's not exactly clear what you want the result to be, please edit your original question and show the desired result using the sample data you provided.

Answer (score 1):

This is the official MS example:

```
SELECT 'AverageCost' AS Cost_Sorted_By_Production_Days, 
[0], [1], [2], [3], [4]
FROM
(SELECT DaysToManufacture, StandardCost 
    FROM Production.Product) AS SourceTable
PIVOT
(
AVG(StandardCost)
FOR DaysToManufacture IN ([0], [1], [2], [3], [4])
) AS PivotTable;
```

That's a pivot of the data from this:

```
USE AdventureWorks2008R2 ;
GO
SELECT DaysToManufacture, AVG(StandardCost) AS AverageCost 
FROM Production.Product
GROUP BY DaysToManufacture;
```

which produces this

```
DaysToManufacture          AverageCost    
0                          5.0885    
1                          223.88    
2                          359.1082    
4                          949.4105
```

As you can see they've specified the pivoted columns explicitly - it's not data-driven. To ge things totally data driven you essentially have to do two passes, the first one generating the column names into a string template. The second pass executes that generated SQL.

```
DECLARE @dyncols AS VARCHAR(MAX) = (SELECT 
  STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ',' + QUOTENAME(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), YOURPIVOTCOL)) 
  FROM YOURTABLE FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).VALUE('.', 'VARCHAR(MAX)'),1,1,''))
```